# ECS and Application Load Balancer Ephemeral Ports using Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

I tried to build an ECS cluster with ALB in front using terraform. As I used dynamic port mappping the targets will not be registerd as healthy. I played with the  healthcheck and Success codes if I set it to 301 everything is fine.

[image]

Comment: Is there a question here? And it might be helpful if you can post your Terraform code as well if you're having an issue with it. Ideally this should be in the form of a [mcve] so people can more easily understand it and run your Terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Looks like the code above is working. I had different issue with networking.

Answer (score 0):

**ECS**

```
data "template_file" "mb_task_template" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/marketplace-backend.json.tpl")
  vars = {
    name      = "${var.mb_image_name}"
    port      = "${var.mb_port}"
    image     = "${aws_ecr_repository.mb.repository_url}"
    log_group = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.mb.name}"
    region    = "${var.region}"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "mb" {
  name = var.mb_image_name
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "mb" {
  family                = var.mb_image_name
  container_definitions = data.template_file.mb_task_template.rendered
  volume {
    name      = "mb-home"
    host_path = "/ecs/mb-home"
  }
}


resource "aws_ecs_service" "mb" {
  name            = var.mb_repository_url
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.mb.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.mb.arn
  desired_count   = 2
  iam_role        = var.aws_iam_role_ecs
  depends_on      = [aws_autoscaling_group.mb]
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = var.target_group_arn
    container_name   = var.mb_image_name
    container_port   = var.mb_port
  }
}


resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "mb" {
  name                      = var.mb_image_name
  availability_zones        = ["${var.availability_zone}"]
  min_size                  = var.min_instance_size
  max_size                  = var.max_instance_size
  desired_capacity          = var.desired_instance_capacity
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.mb.name
  vpc_zone_identifier       = flatten([var.vpc_zone_identifier])
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/user_data.tpl")
  vars = {
    ecs_cluster_name = "${var.mb_image_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "mb" {
  name_prefix                 = var.mb_image_name
  image_id                    = var.ami
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  security_groups             = ["${var.aws_security_group}"]
  iam_instance_profile        = var.aws_iam_instance_profile
  key_name                    = var.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data                   = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "mb" {
  name              = var.mb_image_name
  retention_in_days = 14
}
```

**ALB**

```
locals {
  target_groups = ["1", "2"]
}

resource "aws_alb" "mb" {
  name               = "${var.mb_image_name}-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = ["${aws_security_group.mb_alb.id}"]
  subnets            = var.subnets
  tags = {
    Name = var.mb_image_name
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "mb" {
  count       = length(local.target_groups)
  name        = "${var.mb_image_name}-tg-${element(local.target_groups, count.index)}"
  port        = var.mb_port
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "instance"
  health_check {
    path                = "/health"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    timeout             = "10"
    interval            = "15"
    healthy_threshold   = "3"
    unhealthy_threshold = "3"
    matcher             = "200-299"
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  tags = {
    Name = var.mb_image_name
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "mb_https" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.mb.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = module.dns.certificate_arn
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.mb.0.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "mb_https" {
  listener_arn = aws_alb_listener.mb_https.arn
  priority     = 100
  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.mb.0.arn
  }
  condition {
    field  = "path-pattern"
    values = ["/health/"]
  }
}
```